# How to know when QSerialPort is ready for more data in Qt5?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, serial-port, qt5, qtserialport

**Is there some way to be notified when my serial device is ready to receive more data?**

I am implementing a program that feeds commands to a servo controller over serial using the *asynchronous* API of [QSerialPort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html). The program works, but it seems that I am experiencing congestion.

In my application I keep a registry of most updated servo position that I wish to synchronize with the controller with as low latency as possible. My attempt at pushing new data to the serial port as quickly as time lets me leads to what I think is a buildup of data that makes the communication break down altogether.

My question is, can I be notified when the serial interface is ready to receive new data somehow while using `QSerialPort` in *asynchronous* mode?

The only other option I see is to use *synchronous* mode and call [waitForBytesWritten()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#waitForBytesWritten) But I really don't want to do that.

NOTE: I have studied the [serial port examples in the Qt5 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-examples.html) carefully, but the [example for asynchronous write](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-cwriterasync-example.html) does not provide the information I need, as it perform a one-shot send before quitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to the signal `bytesWritten` and check `bytesToWrite` to determine if the write buffer is empty. Both are inherited from `QIODevice`.

Comment: You mean check bytesToWrite from within the bytesWritten handler?

Comment: Yes. The bytesWritten handler could be called several times, but only when bytesToWrite reaches zero the write buffer will be empty.

Comment: I had made my own counter not knowing about bytesWritten(), but that did not work very well. simply replacing my variable with that call and everything is dandy.