# Calling slot in another thread doesn´t get called

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class with a serial interface which transmit some data and `emit` a `MessageReceived` signal when some valid data are received:

**Serial.c**

```
void Serial::on_serialPort_readData()
{
        ... Other stuff...

        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Received in serial";
            emit MessageReceived(_mReceivedData);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have my main window which opens the serial connection and start the message transaction. But I have to receive a lot of data and the transmission will take a while, so I decided to use a `QThread` for the processing of the received data.

I created a thread and a worker in my `mainwindow.cpp` (code from [here](https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage)):

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
_mThread = new QThread(this);
_mThreadWorker = new Worker();
_mThreadWorker->moveToThread(_mThread);

// Like in the example
connect(_mThread, &QThread::started, _mThreadWorker, &Worker::Progress);
connect(_mThreadWorker, &Worker::Finished, _mThread, &QThread::quit);
connect(_mThreadWorker, &Worker::Finished, _mThreadWorker, &Worker::deleteLater);
connect(_mThread, &QThread::finished, _mThread, &QObject::deleteLater);

connect(_mProtocolInterface, &Serial::MessageReceived, _mThreadWorker, &Worker::UpdateData);

_mThread->start();

// Send the first packet so the receiver will answer
```

The serial interface will send the data in different packages and I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559610/how-to-setup-qserialport-on-a-separate-thread) that it is a bad idea to use the serial port in a seperate thread, so I decided to use the serial port in the main thread and connect the `MessageReceived` signal with an `UpdateData` slot of my worker:

**worker.h**

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    ...

    public slots:
        void Progress(void);
        void UpdateData(QByteArray Data);

    public:
        Worker(QObject* parent = nullptr);
        ~Worker();
        ...
};
```

**worker.cpp**

```
void Worker::UpdateData(QByteArray Data)
{
    qDebug() << "Received in Worker";
    _mData = Data;
}

void Worker::Progress(void)
{
    while(_mActive)
    {
        switch(_mState)
        {
            case STATE_INIT:
            {
                _mState = STATE_INIT;
                // Just a idle to simulate the data transfer during debugging
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But only the slot `on_serialPort_readData` gets called after I receive the data from the receiver:

```
>> Received in serial
```

So why the slot `UpdateData` of the class `Worker` doesn´t get called?

Comment: Your `MessageReceived` signal declared in `Protocol`, but you emit it from the `Serial` class as if it's `Serial::MessageReveived` signal.

Comment: @vahancho sorry this was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Your code is incomplete but `Worker::Progress` appears to be a loop that never returns control to the Qt event processing loop.  Hence no queued/inter-thread signals will be processed.  You *must* have an active event loop on the receiver's thread.

Comment: Since QSerialPort is asynchronous I don't see a need for QThread here at all.

Comment: mmh okay. So I have to change the code. Thank you.